# Should i set up a BK/NK on a DimGeography table?

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

I'm just in the beginning stages of creating our data warehouse.

Our LOBS hold many different addresses relating to people, locations, sites, etc.

When creating the DimGeography table should i look to setup a Business/Natural Key or what would be the best practise in storing addresses relating to numerous data sets.

Thanks in advance

Will.

Comment: This is way to vague to answer without knowing a great deal more about what the data your dealing with is. Personally, I've never even used a Geography table - I would put a client's address on DimClient and a store location on DimStore, but that's all really situational. Where possibly, you should certainly have a column containing whatever identifier it is that you use for each record in the source system, so that you can build your fact easily.

Comment: The data is customer data and site data . We will need to report on regional information and so this is why i thought there would be a need for a common dimgeography table.  Do you report by location out of your DW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i opted to use SSIS to load into the DimGeography table side stepping the idea of introducing every single address into the table and referencing back and forth.

The problem would have been SSIS load time if i had put addresses in the DimCustomer table as i have quite a lot of customers and also have broken down some of the information creating fullname information and fullname plus title to avoid reporting speed problems during cubing/reporting.

If anybody has any retrospective comments they are more than welcome :)